# Read value from JSON array in Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb

I need to get value from an sub-array for field `groups`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("538726124ba2222c0c0248a8"),
    "create_date" : "2014-05-29 14:20:34",
    "update_date" : "2016-02-12 11:21:23",
    "groups" : [
        "54c91b2c4ba222182e636943"
    ]
}
```

I'm using following code in MongoDB.

```
var pa = db.door_parameters.find({});
pa.forEach(function(doc) {
            printjson(doc.groups);
});
```

That gives me the results as array for example: `[ "54c91b2c4ba222182e636943" ]`

I need only string "54c91b2c4ba222182e636943" without brackets.

I tried with `doc.groups0`,`doc.groups[0]`, `doc.groups['0']` but that doesn't give me expected results.

Answer (score 0):

```
pa.forEach(function(doc) {
            doc.groups.forEach(function(g) { printjson(g) });
});
```